# I need a random code for Arduino Uno to trigger a single relay

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to get a random triggering of a single relay from an Arduino Uno. I would also ultimately like to be able to adjust the speed that the random triggering happens at. How are the times between the randoms adjusted?
I have tried some codes and have the relay hooked up to pin 8 on the Uno, and would like more control. Thanks

```
void setup () {
pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
}


void loop() {

long randnumber;
long randnumber2;
long randnumber5;
long randnumber6;

randomSeed(analogRead(A0));

randnumber = random(5, 9);
randnumber2 = random(5,9);
randnumber5 = random(3370,498);
randnumber6 = random(537,4370);

digitalWrite(randnumber, HIGH);
digitalWrite(randnumber2, LOW);
delay(randnumber5);
digitalWrite(randnumber, LOW);
digitalWrite(randnumber2, HIGH);
delay(randnumber5);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the sketch you are using now?

Comment: Use the blink-without-delay https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay Remove the 'const' of the variable interval, and use random https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/random-numbers/random/ for the interval. Set the new random interval inside the if-statement. Adjust the min and max parameters of the random for speed control.

Comment: VE7JRO, Here is the code I have so far:       void setup () {

pinMode(8, OUTPUT);


}
void loop() {

long randnumber;
long randnumber2;
long randnumber5;
long randnumber6;

randomSeed(analogRead(A0));

randnumber = random(5, 9);
randnumber2 = random(5,9);
randnumber5 = random(3370,498);
randnumber6 = random(537,4370);

digitalWrite(randnumber, HIGH);
digitalWrite(randnumber2, LOW);
delay(randnumber5);
digitalWrite(randnumber, LOW);
digitalWrite(randnumber2, HIGH);
delay(randnumber5);
}

Comment: This is my 1st Arduino project

Comment: @WaddyP consider editing your original post by adding your code section. Non trival code in a comment section is nearly unreadable.

Comment: Yeah, don't post multiple lines of code in comments. Edit your question and add the code using code tags.

Comment: RamblinRose, don't know how to do that. I am new here

Comment: there are 4 buttons just below your question .... one of then is `edit`